# python requests add hyper http2 feature got "Bad Request (Invalid Header Name)" error

Tags: python, python-requests

```
def jiexi_iqiyi(url):
     # some other stuff
     get_m3u8_api = "https://api.47ks.com/config/webmain.php"
     data = {
       "k": k,
       "k2": k2,
       "ep": ep,
       "cip": cip,
       "cip_hex": cip_hex,
       "csign": csign,
       "tm": tm,
       "v": v,
       "pt": pt,
       "nip": nip,
       "from": from_,
       "mode": mode
    }
    data_string = ''
    #To calculate content-length
    for key, value in data.items():
         data_string += key + "=" + value.replace("?","%3F").replace("/", "%2F").replace("%2B", "%252B").replace(":","%3A") + "&"
    data_string = data_string[0:-1]
    content_length = len(data_string)

    #HTTP2 new feature:add headers startwith ":"
    headers = {
        ":authority" : "api.47ks.com",
        ":method" : "POST",
        ":path" : "/config/webmain.php",
        ":scheme" : "https",
        "accept" : "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "accept-encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br",
        "accept-language" : "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8",
        "cache-control" : "no-cache",
        "content-length" : str(content_length),
        "content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "cookie" : "47KS_uuid=0ba0439b-56a4-98d7-f974-33a023914016; 47KS_upid=d3JJeXlSdDA5QmRFVF9sUjNkY2pZbVlicWZxdGF5dzNBV2UwYkhXRDFRRTYvM3diMFhIN0hVVHBsazY3VTJUMmhLWTU1Y2VDdDFnTE8yeGpTVnFvVUltUWkvRUQwcTd2TDFpb2wyeWI3RU0vUnBoMXkzdmJmQk0%3D; UM_distinctid=160300441d91e7-0694eb159e8a5-7910717d-1fa400-160300441da117; yd_srvbl=7a0951e72b6b3906e732575bc0dda444; CNZZDATA1260594368=1355421933-1512629667-null%7C1512651272",
        "origin" : "https://api.47ks.com",
        "pragma" : "no-cache",
        "referer" : "https://api.47ks.com/webcloud/?v="+url,
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.104 Safari/537.36 Core/1.53.4399.400 QQBrowser/9.7.12777.400",
        "x-requested-with" : "XMLHttpRequest",
}
    s = requests.Session()
    s.mount("https://api.47ks.com/", HTTP20Adapter())
    r = s.post(get_m3u8_api, data=data,headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
```

I got a 400 HTTP error:

## Bad Request (Invalid Header Name)

- When I comment out all the headers include User-Agent,got a 405 not allowed error.
- When I just use requests HTTP1, I got error message:请求被拒绝，如有疑问请联系管理员！Means: Your request has been refused,please contact the system manager.I guess that because this website only allows HTTP2 request.
- I am pretty sure: all the post data is correct.

How to fix this?